# Report Services (SSRS) 2005 connect database in Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, sql-server-2014

Currently I am working on a project it is request us to connect their database (Server A with Microsoft SQL Server 2014) via SSRS (Server B with Microsoft SQL Server 2005).

I keep facing the problem with this message :

> The version of the report server database is either in a format that
>   is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '162'. The
>   expected version is 'C.0.8.54'. To continue, update the version of the
>   report server database and verify access rights.
>   (rsInvalidReportServerDatabase) (rsRPCError) Get Online Help

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make sure you are using BIDS 2005 to develop reports to be deployed to your SSRS 2005 server.

Comment: How to make sure? If I use BIDS 2005 the sure can connect with SQL server 2014 Database Report SErver?

Comment: Please clarify your setup.  Your original question sounds like you are hosting reports on a 2005 server, and those reports only query a relational database on 2014.   Are you in fact publishing reports to a 2014 SSRS server?

Comment: Yes. you are correct. So, can make it?

Comment: Well that's not really what I would call a clarification.   I have no idea, you'll have to spell out exactly what servers you are using for what purpose.

Comment: my question have mention that **Server A** as SSRS and **Server B** as Database of ReportServer. ReportServer is the database use for SSRS.

Comment: I've just noticed that the above comment contradicts what you have written in the question, which is that the database is on *Server A*. Please can you clarify?

Comment: Server A is SSRS, 2005
Server B is Sql Server 2014 (SSRS 2005 from Server A is pointing this DB).
Server C is SQL server 2014 (Db here migrate to Server B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is likely to be that the ReportServer database has been created using SQL Server **2014**. Trying to connection a SQL Server 2005 Report Server installation to that database will not work because they are not compatible. If it is possible to run Reporting Services with a configuration like this at all, and I'm not sure that it is, you will need to have a ReportServer database that was created using SQL Server **2005** Reporting Services Configuration Manager.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but what if I need to restore the ReportServer Database by 2014 version to Server A?

Comment: I don't follow you - if you have created the database on server A (SQL 2014) then you should not have any problems restoring it to server A. You should be creating the database on Server A (2014) by using the RSCM on Server B (2005) for this to have any chance of working.

Comment: Hi @nathan,
 I do create the database by the way you mention. It is works. My problem now is after restore db from Server C. It pop up error and mention that :
'Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RPCException: The feature: "Scale-out deployment" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsOperationNotSupported), ; 
Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RPCException: The feature: "Scale-out deployment" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsOperationNotSupported) '

Comment: Server A is SSRS, 2005
Server B is Sql Server 2014 (SSRS 2005 from Server A is pointing this DB).
Server C is SQL server 2014 (Db here migrate to Server B)

Comment: Sorry, your original question didn't mention server C at all and I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. You should save yourself a world of pain and install the SQL 2005 database engine on Server A (since it is already licensed for SQL 2005) and use that to host the 2005 SSRS instance ReportServer database. That way you are only dealing with one version of SQL Server and will avoid all these problems.

Comment: If you are trying to scale out your SSRS environment by hosting the Reporting Services and database components on separate servers then I would suggest that you don't attempt this unless all the servers are running the same version of SQL Server.